# Add data to Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

[image]
I have some problems when trying to add .csv files to my Google Colab
I already added these file to my Drive, and copy its exact links to my notebooks, but I still received error File not found
Please help me
My data files 're more than 25 MB, so I cannot add them from Github

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding the files using Upload option from files tab in the left side of your colab notebook.

[image]